# uvc_camera not launching in ros groovy

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get this error when
roslaunch uvc_camera camera_node.launch is run in a terminal.

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [uvc_camera/uvc_camera]: can't locate node [uvc_camera] in package [uvc_camera]

ROS groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78531/uvc_camera-not-launching-in-ros-groovy./) by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no uvc_camera package included in groovy, I don't know why. It appears again in hydro.

However there's a package in the repository called ros-groovy-usb-cam.
Install, then run "rosrun usb-cam usb_cam_node"
Alternatively you can also use ros-groovy-gscam (http://wiki.ros.org/gscam).

(Related question and more detailed answers: http://answers.ros.org/question/57320/package-for-simple-usb-web-camera-in-groovy/)

---

Originally posted by [andreas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1031/andreas/) with karma: 168 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2013-11-18**:
Thanks! but i switched to hydro and I get this package not found error with custom Catkin packages so I am building packages with rosbuild for now.